# Getting 404 at main page of bluemix.net

Tags: ibm-cloud

I'm trying to access https://console.ng.bluemix.net/ and I'm getting a 404 Resource Not Found. Did the URL changed or is there an alternative URL to access ??

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently an access issue with the Bluemix US-South region. We are working to get service restored as quickly as possible. Check the [Bluemix Status page](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status) for updates.